# Ingress Nginx use regex in Server snippet

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-method: POST
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: id
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: http://auth.default.svc.cluster.local:8000/authenticate
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: error_page 401 /error/401;
      error_page 403 /error/403;
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: location = /fhir/{
      auth_request /auth/; auth_request_set $id $upstream_http_id;
      proxy_pass http://pth-auth.default.svc.cluster.local:8000/authenticate; proxy_set_header x-tenant-id $id;
      proxy_method POST; error_page 401 /error/401; error_page 403 /error/403;} location = /error/401 { proxy_method
      POST; proxy_pass http://auth.default.svc.cluster.local:8000/error/401; }
      location = /error/403 { proxy_method POST; proxy_pass http://auth.default.svc.cluster.local:8000/error/403;
      } location = /auth/ { proxy_pass http://auth.default.svc.cluster.local:8000/authenticate; proxy_method POST;
      proxy_set_header x-original-method $request_method; proxy_set_header x-original-uri $request_uri;}
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
  name: ingress-nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: xyz
              servicePort: 80
```

In server snippet for location = /fhir/ I want to match any pattern that has /fhir/(.*) but I'm not able to find any good solution for this. Currently it is working as exact match.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Give some examples of expected rewrite results.

Comment: Let say if I want to hit /fhir/version or fhir/example or something like this it should match /fhir/ location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked worked for me
location ~* "^/fhir/.*" {whatever you want to write in here}
This will match anything that has prefix fhir.Took refernce from here https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/